# React app build fails in Docker in Jenkins, but not locally

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, npm, create-react-app

On my local machine, `npm run build` works just fine. On my Docker image launched via Jenkins, I get issues like

```
Cannot find module: 'file-saver'. Make sure this package is installed.

You can install this package by running: npm install file-saver.
```

and

```
FAIL src/core/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'surface-nets' from 'vtext.js'
```

On my local machine, I have cleared the npm cache (`npm cache clean -f`), removed `node_modules/`, and reinstalled (`npm i`). I have even used `npm update` and the [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) package to update everything. I installed all peer dependencies. My local copy should be as wiped-clean as the copy within Docker is. In the Jenkinsfile, I put `npm list` and it shows `surface-nets` and `file-saver` and all my other packages. I also put `ls node_modules/` and I can see the package folders are there. I have reduced my Dockerfile down to just 1 line: `FROM node:current`.

Why is it saying "Cannot find module" when the modules are installed?

Comment: I got around this issue by creating a new branch and pushing that into my Jenkins multi-branch pipeline. On the new branch, the exact same Jenkinsfile, Dockerfile, package.json, etc. just worked as it was supposed to. I have no idea why the old branch got... uh, "broken?". It was just broken with no explanation so far, so I guess there's something inside Jenkins that was being cached or some environment piece that got messed up or *something*. But just making a new branch fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of this issue is still unknown, but I did find out that the repository was corrupted. I ended up wiping the whole remote repo and `git init`-ing a new one, then pushing to that. I assume that corruption contributed to the issue at hand here.